# Get the name of a file given as input in cmd

Tags: java, file-io

I'm currently working on a project and i need some help. Depending on the user input I have to read some data off some txt files. There are three ways to call the program:

```
java Graph [-u] -s start example_graph.txt

java Graph [-u] -a example_graph.txt

java Graph [-u] -d traffic.txt
```

The files i have to read depending on what the user chose are :

> clrs.txt, traffic.txt, traffic_u.txt, facebook_combined_u.txt

The method I'm using to read and store the data of the file is

public void readFile() {

```
    String txtFile = "filename.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String txtSplitBy = ",";
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] dj = line.split(txtSplitBy);
            int node_a = Integer.parseInt(dj[0]);
            int node_b = Integer.parseInt(dj[1]);
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(dj[2]);
            if (node_a > adj.size()) {
                for (int i = adj.size() + 1; i <= node_a; i++) {
                    adj.add(new HashSet<Link>());
                }
            }
            HashSet<Link> h = adj.get(node_a);
            h.add(new Link(node_b, weight));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But this method only works if I have a specific file as input. Now that there are more than one files how can I get the file name into a String?

Comment: You receive them in the args of the main method

Comment: Start by using the new file API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can read arguments from the cmd line in the args area of the main method, for example:

```
public class SO {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String s : args){ //For each argument
        if(s.indexOf(".") != -1){ //If contains a dot (like a file ext)
            System.out.println(s); //print
        }
    }
 }
}
```

When running this with:

```
java SO [-u] -a example_graph.txt
```

It wrote out the name of the file.

Hope this helps!